# How to prove that the Peterson inner product of $E_k$ with a cusp eigenform is $0$?

Tags: modular-forms

How to prove that the Peterson inner product of $E_k$ and $f$ is $0$ where $f \in S_k$ is an eigenform for all of the level $1$ Hecke operators?

Comment: We've had this question before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450412/modular-form-petersson-inner-product

Answer (score 4):

The Hecke algebra is self-adjoint with respect to the Petersson inner product. For a modular form $g$ denote $a_n(g)$ its $n$-th Fourier coefficient. Since $f$ and $E_k$ are eigenforms, for any $n>0$ we have

$$a_n(E_k) \left<E_k, f\right> = \left<T_n E_k, f\right> = \left<E_k, T_n f\right> = a_n(f) \left<E_k, f\right>$$

so if we had $\left <E_k, f\right> \neq 0$, we would have $a_n(E_k) = a_n(f)$ for all $n>0$. This would imply that $E_k-f$ is the constant $1$, which is absurd because constants are of weight $0$ but here $k>0$.

Comment: Hi, I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28893/hecke-operators-on-modular-forms). I'm reading chapters 6-9 of [Diamond & Shurman](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf), could you help with the Hecke operators acting on the Jacobian variety $J(X_1(N))$ (p.238) ?

Comment: I understand that letting $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^g$ to be the (eigenforms) basis of $S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$ then $J(X(N)) = \mathbb{C}^g / \Lambda$ with $\Lambda = \{ (\int_\gamma f_1(z)dz, \ldots , \int_\gamma f_g(z)dz), \  \gamma \text{ is a closed loop}\}$ but then I don't get the variety associated to $f$ and the Hecke operators acting on the Jacobian side.